# Changing the name of BM70 BLE module without Microchip's evaluation board

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, msp430, microchip

I am trying to customize the name of my BM70 BLE module. I am not using the BM70 PICTail evaluation board. Instead I am using the MSP430F4799 microcontroller to communicate with the module and to configure the P2_0 pin and other necessary hardware pins. I tried with the UI configuration tool and manual pattern test tool to change the name of the BM70 module with the COM port where the UART of the MSP430 is connected but it did not work. Now my question is there any way to access command set protocol of BM70 module without using the PICTail evaluation board?

Comment: If you have still problems with the BM70 module try to switch to RN4870. It's the same module with a different firmware. The RN4870 could really easy communicate with AT commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that in the same way as BM71 module. You can read about the whole process in my blog at [bijan.binaee.com/index.php/2018/08/03/bm71-no-uart-response/](http://bijan.binaee.com/index.php/2018/08/03/bm71-no-uart-response/)

ps: I wish I could post this as a comment but I don't have required reputation at this community (If you are a moderator I appreciate if you delete this answer and make it as a comment if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use your MSP 430. Please have a look at the [BM70 user guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002542A.pdf). There are some hardware connections required to interface the module (see page 63). You had to use the default baudrate to connect the module the first time.